# facebook "publish_actions" can be removed BUT IS NEEDED

Tags: facebook, permissions

I've got an app that NEEDS publish_actions, since its posting and retrieving the score for the users and creating the leaderboard with this data, so one can compete with friends for the best highscore.

The app is asking for publish_actions during its authorisation, after that saving, reading etc. -> it all works great! BUT the user has the chance to REMOVE this publish_actions permission by clicking this little |x| right next to it, either in the firt app-auth-screen or app config later on. Problem there: Once a user does that, which some will cause why grant rights you (so it seems) dont have to grant, the app cant write the gaming score in its profile, and of course, his/her friends will never know what score he has. Meaning: if the publish_actions gets removed, the app does not work and makes no sense whatsoever.

The question: Is there a way to check for that permission on app-start, alerting the player that the app wont work correctly ... or better yet, re-show the auth-screen asking for the publish_actions permission again? Cause once its removed, the publish_actions permission cannot be un-removed. The user would have to remove the whole app an launch it again.

I would really appreciate a little help here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/permissions
```

Returns a json object with the permissions the user has granted to your app.

You should read more about it here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/handling-revoked-permissions/

Comment: Thank you ... I was working in AS3 with a plugin and kinda found a solution/workaround for my situation shortly before your comment -___- ... no Idea how I missed that! I post the save score command and listen to any errors coming back, like (permission "publish_actions" needed) ... if so, I log the user out and log him in again, and so prompting him with the auth-screen